# SQL Server Linux Disable Remote Connections

Tags: sql-server, linux

What is the best way to disable remote connections on a SQL Server Install on Linux (CentOS 7)? I.E. force SSH Tunneling to connect over localhost.

I typically block ports explicitly with IPTables/Firewalld rules, and have 1443 closed off to the outside.

However with MySQL I also tend to close off users to local access only, i.e. 'testUser'@'localhost' and not 'testUser'@'%'. Also, the default if you run `mysql-secure-installation` is to turn of remote connections as root (SA in SQL Server). This ensures that if my network is breached, they still have to SSH Tunnel into the server.

How do I achieve this?

I was reading this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-access-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017) and was not able to turn off remote connections when running:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'remote access', 0 ;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE ;  
GO
```

Comment: Have you tried configuring SQL Serverto only listen on a loopback address?  Something like:   ‘ipaddress = 127.0.0.1’

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft No. Sounds like that would be the solution but I can't find any documentation on how to do that. Haven't see documentation that mentions where config files are on Linux or what the transact SQL would look like for that statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to David Browne for pointing me in the right direction. Sometimes knowing what terms to search for is the hardest part. I also got direction from [this article](https://www.sqlshack.com/configure-sql-server-2017-linux-mssql-conf-available-tools/)

So to change the SQL Server to listen on `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` all you have to do is add the following configuration to the file `/var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf`:

```
[network]
ipaddress = 127.0.0.1
```

then restart the server with:

```
sudo systemctl restart mssql-server
```

If you want to get a complete list of all configuration parameters you can run

```
/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf list
```

Note a sample of the output is like

```
hadr.hadrenabled                           Allow SQL Server to use availability groups for high availability and disaster recovery
language.lcid                              Locale identifier for SQL Server to use (e.g. 1033 for US - English)
memory.memorylimitmb                       SQL Server memory limit (megabytes)
network.disablesssd                        Disable querying SSSD for AD account information and default to LDAP calls
network.enablekdcfromkrb5conf              Enable looking up KDC information from krb5.conf
network.forceencryption                    Force encryption of incoming client connections
network.forcesecureldap                    Force using LDAPS to contact domain controller
network.ipaddress                          IP address for incoming connections
```

So you can add any of those to the `/var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf` file. The syntax is that the prefix before the dot goes in square brackets with the suffix listed below (see above for example).

To test it was working I checked:

1) That the applications using it were up

2) Running `sudo nmap -PN <servername>` to determine if the port was open

3) Trying to open a connection from a remote computer where I previously could with `sqlcmd -S <servername> -U <username>` which threw the error

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login timeout expired.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : TCP Provider: Error code 0x2749.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
```

Comment: This is the sort of knowledge sharing we want to encourage around here